# Testing membership of elliptic curve points in subgroups of binary extension fields

Tags: finite-groups, extension-field, elliptic-curves, galois-extensions

I come from an engineering background. Let a binary extension field $GF(2^{233})$ and a finite group $E$ made of points defined by a curve over Binary Fields i.e. $y^2 + xy = x^3 + x^2 + b$ with constructing polynomial $f(z)=z^{233}+z^{74}+1$ and let a subgroup $C \subset E$ only with elements that are created from doubling another point in $E$, i.e. $C(GF(2^m))=\{P+P:P \in E(GF(2^m)\}$.

Is there a way to test if a given element - point $a$ is a member of $C$ and what restrictions should apply on $E$ and $C$ for this test to be valid?

Thank you for your time,

Comment: A Galois Field of order $2^m$ (i.e., $\mathbb{F}_{2^m}=GF(2^m)$) is a field of characteristic 2. This means that $x+x=0$. So $C(GF(2^m))=\{0\}$. So the only element is 0.

Comment: That’s true for $GF(2)$, not $GF(2^m)$ otherwise you wouldn’t be able to define additive abelian groups in various cases, eg. binary elliptic curves. Also + is not always typical addition obviously (maybe I need to depict it differently?), eg. in elliptic curves addition is defined geometrically under point addition with elements in $GF(2^m)$

Comment: You'll need to better define your terms. $GF(2^m)$ denotes the Galois field of order $2^m$ (all finite extensions of $GF(2)$ are of this form). It *does* have characteristic $2$ and so $x+x=0$ for all $x$. So either $GF(2^m)$ means something different to you or your addition is not the addition in the field.

Comment: OK I ll restrict it for binary elliptic curves and lets see then.

Comment: The addition is the addition on the elliptic curve.

Comment: I think I can give you some help, but it’ll have to wait a couple of hours more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Notations:* The multiplication-by-two map $[2]$ is known algebraically, it is a map
$$
[2]\ :\ E(F)\to E(F)\ ,
$$
mapping $P\in E(F)$ into the point $2P:=P+P\in E(F)$, where the addition $+$ is the structural addition on the elliptic curve w.r.t. the neutral infinity point $O$. Here, $F$ is the finite field with $2^{233}$ elements, constructed as
$$
F = \Bbb F_2[X]\ \text{ modulo }\ \underbrace{z^{233}+z^{74}+1}_{f}\ ,
$$
and $E$ is the given elliptic curve over $F$ with affine equation
$$
\tag{$E$}
Y^2 + XY = X^3 + X^2 + b\ ,
$$
where $B$ is some *a priori* fixed parameter in $F$.
The question regards

---

So let us get explicitly the formula for $2P$, starting from an affine point $P=(x,y)$, $P\ne O$. (For $O$ the situation is clear, $O=2O$ is in the image of $[2]$.) To compute the tangent in $(x,y)$ we write $X=x+\xi$, $Y=y+\eta$, and get the linear part in $\xi$ and $\eta$ after substitution in the affine $(X,Y)$-equation of the curve. So we get successively (formally):
$$
\begin{aligned}
Y^2 + XY &= X^3 + X^2 + b\ ,\\
(y+\eta)^2 + (x+\xi)(y+\eta) &= (x+\xi)^3 + (x+\xi)^2 + b\ ,\\
2y\eta + x\eta+y\xi &= 3x^2\xi +2x\xi + O(\xi^2,\xi\eta,\eta^2)\ ,\\
x\eta+y\xi &= x^2\xi + O(\xi^2,\xi\eta,\eta^2)\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
(characteristic two case, so here and below $1=-1$ and $2=0$,)
so the needed tangent has equation
$
x\eta =(x^2-y)\xi
$.
Going back to $X,Y$ via $\xi = X-x$, $\eta=Y-y$, it is the affine line equation
$$
\tag{$L$}
Y=y+\frac 1x(x^2-y)(X-x)=mX+n\ ,\qquad
m := \frac 1x(x^2-y)
\ .
$$
So we have to solve the system built from the two equations,
$(E)$ and $(L)$.

*Note:* In case $x=0$, we cannot use $x$ as a denominator, so the tangent is
$x(Y-y)=(x^2-y)(X-x)$, i.e. $0=(0-y)(X-0)$, i.e.
the vertical line $X=0$, inserting this we get $Y^2=b=y^2$, i.e. $(Y-y)^2=0$, the affine point $P=(0,y)$ is a double solution, and the third intersection point is not an affine point, but the infinity point. Using this information, we see that $2P=P+P=O$, so $P=(0,y)$ is in $C$.

Consider the case $x\ne 0$. Then we substitute $Y$ from $(L)$ in $(E)$ getting,
$$
(mX+n)^2
+
X(mX+n)
=
X^3 +X^2+b\ ,
$$
and there are three solutions, the first two are known, $x$ and $x$, and the third one, $x'$ say, is wanted, so that their sum is (Vieta) obtained by isolating (minus) the coefficient of $X^2$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
x'
&= x' + x + x
= 1+m+m^2
\\
&=
1
+ \frac 1x(x^2-y)
+ \frac 1{x^2}(x^2-y)^2
=
1
+ \frac 1x(x^2+y)
+ \frac 1{x^2}(x^4+y^2)
\\
&= 1 + x + \frac yx + x^2 +\frac {y^2}{x^2} 
= 1 + x + x^2 +\frac 1{x^2}(y^2+xy)
\\
&= 1 + x + x^2 +\frac 1{x^2}(x^3 + x^2+b )
= 1 + x + x^2 + x + 1 +\frac bx
\\
&=x^2 +\frac b{x^2}
\ .
\\[3mm]
&\qquad\text{ For $y'$ we use the line equation, getting}
\\[3mm]
y' &= y+\frac 1x(x^2-y)(x'-x)\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
The point $2P$ is obtained from $(x',y')=-2P$ by intersecting $(E)$ with the
"vertical line" $X=x'$ through $(x',y')$ and the infinity point $O$, getting the third intersection point $(x'',y'')$. Of course, $x''=x'$, and Vieta gives us for $y''$ the second solution with $Y^2+x'Y=\dots$ so $y'+y''=x'$.

---

We can, if we want so, get an explicit formula, but we do not need it in our case. We can now restate the problem: If a point $Q=(x'',y'')$ in $E(F)$ is given, does there exist a point $P=(x,y)$ with $2P=Q$ (i.e. equivalently $Q\in C$)?

This amounts to solving in the unknown $x$ first the equation
$$
\begin{aligned}
x' &= x^2 +\frac b{x^2}\ ,\qquad\text{i.e.}\\
0 &=x^4 +x'\;x^2 +b\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
and if it has at least one solution in $F$, then $y',x'', y''$ are easily determined in a linear fashion. Solving involves to steps of getting the square roots in $F$, if both steps lead to at least one solution, then the starting point $Q$ is in $2C$.

---

---

Let us see this working in a special example.

The following [sage](https://www.sagemath.org) code is giving an explicit example for the field $F=\Bbb F_2[u]=\Bbb F_2[U]/f(U)=\Bbb F_2[U]/(U^{233}+U^{74}+1)$. Here $u$ is the image of $U$ taken modulo $f(U)$.

We initialize some sample curve, taking $b=u^4 + u^2$.
Then the point $Q=(u+1, u^2+1)$ is a point on the curve.

```
R.<U> = PolynomialRing(GF(2))
F.<u> = GF(2^233, modulus=U^233 + U^74 + 1)

b = u^4 + u^2
E = EllipticCurve(F, [1, 1, 0, 0, b])
Q = E.point( (u + 1, u^2 + 1, 1) )
```

So the question is if $Q$ is of the shape $2P$ for some $P=(x,y)$.
We solve
$$
x^4 + (u+1)x^2 + (u^4+u^2) = 0
$$
in $F$. Note that $(u+1)$ is a square in $F$, explicitly:
$$
\underbrace{
(u^{228} + u^{191} + u^{154} 
+ u^{117} + u^{69} + u^{32} + 1)}_{\text{Notation: }v}{}^2
=u+1\ .
$$
So we deal with the equation $x^4+v^2\;x^2+ (uv)^2=0$. This is
$$
(x^2+v\; x+ uv^2)^2=0\ ,
$$
and it turns out, that $x^2 +vx+uv^2$ it has two roots w.r.t. variable $x$ in $F$. To get them, we divide first by $v^2$, so the new (Artin-Schreier) equation is
$$
W^2 + W + u=0\ ,\qquad W:=\frac xv\ .
$$
It has a root $w$ in a quadratic extension of $F$, so $w^2+w=u$, and the question is if $w$ is already in $F$. This is indeed so, since $u$ has trace $0$ in $F$, leading to
$$
\begin{aligned}
0 
&=\operatorname{Trace}(u)\\
&=u + u^2 + u^4+ u^8+\dots+u^{2^{232}}\\
&=(w+w^2) + (w+w^2)^2 + (w+w^2)^4+ (w+w^2)^8+\dots+(w+w^2)^{2^{232}}\\
&=(w+w^2) + (w^2+w^4) + (w^4+w^8)+ (w^8+w^{16})+\dots+(w^{2^{232}}+w^{2^{233}})\\
&=w+w^{2^{233}}\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
So $w$ is fixed by the Frobenius of $F$, being thus in $F$.
The trace-zero condition is necessary and sufficient in such cases.

The code computing the point $P$ with $2P=Q$ in this special case is then as follows:

```
v = sqrt(u + 1)
x = (U^2 + v*U + u*v^2).roots(ring=F, multiplicities=False)[0]
P = E.lift_x(x)
print(f'Is  2P = Q? {bool( 2*P == Q)}')
print(f'Is -2P = Q? {bool(-2*P == Q)}')
```

Results:

```
Is  2P = Q? False
Is -2P = Q? True
```

So one of the two lifts above is working.

Comment: Thanks Dan, this pretty much covers it.

Answer (score 1):

Except for your mention of the “constructing polynomial” $f$, I’m pretty sure that I understand your question.

You consider an elliptic curve $E$ whose coefficients are in $\Bbb F_{2^m}$, the field with $2^m$ elements; I’ll just refer to this as $\Bbb F$, since you don’t seem to be changing $m$ throughout your question. And your elliptic curve has equation $Y^2+XY=X^3+X^2+b$, with $b\in\Bbb F$. (The parameter $b$ must be nonzero; otherwise you get a singularity at $(0,0)$, which would make your curve not elliptic.)

You are interested in the group of points $Q$ on $E$, and ask which are of form $P+_EP$, i.e. twice $P$ with respect to the addition on $E$. I’m sure you have seen that the addition on $E$ is by the chord-and-tangent process. That is, to get $P+_EQ=R$, you draw the line connecting $P$ and $Q$ (in $\Bbb F$-geometry, it’s understood) and see what is the third intersection of this line with $E$. This is not $R$, but rather $-_ER$, the inverse of $R$ with respect to the $E$-addition $+_E$. The fact to know is that $R$ and $-_ER$ lie on the same “vertical” line $X=c$. In case $P=Q$, you use the tangent to the curve at $P$ instead of a chord, and proceed.

I’ll use the (by now) standard notation $[n]_E(P)$ for what you get by adding $P$ to itself $n$ times. It’s $n\times P$ with respect to the $E$-addition.

Now, your curve, no matter what $b$ is, has the property that it’s “ordinary”: it has the maximum number of points $p$ with $[2]_E(Q)=\Bbb O$; that’s the neutral element (identity) of the group, and it’s not in the regular (affine) $\Bbb F$-plane, it’s at infinity vertically upwards in the projective plane, with (homogeneous) coordinates $(0:1:0)$. (The opposite of “ordinary” is “supersingular”, and supersingular curves have no points of order the characteristic ($2$ in our case) other than the identity. One such if $Y^2+Y=X^3$.)

Finally here’s the meat of what I can tell you: since the group of all points of $E(\Bbb F)$ is finite and abelian, and since the group $\{Q\in E(\Bbb F):[2]_E(Q)=\Bbb O\}$, that’s the kernel of $[2]$, has only the two elements $\Bbb O$ and $(0,\sqrt b\,)$ (that’s the *unique* element $\beta\in\Bbb F$ with $\beta^2=b$), the “cokernel” of $[2]$ also has order two, $\text{coker}([2])=E(\Bbb F)/\text{image}([2])$. The image of $[2]$ is just the set you’re worried about, the set of things writable as $[2]_E(P)$ for some element $P\in E(\Bbb F)$.

Discomplicating what I just wrote, this means that in all cases, *exactly half* of the points $Q\in E(\Bbb F)$ are of the form $[2](P)$, the points you’re interested in.

But now I have to disappoint you, because I’m not a specialist in this racket, and have no idea how you can tell that a given point $Q=(\xi,\eta)$ is in your good set. But let me give you an example.

In case $m=2$ and $b=1$, the points of $Y^2+XY=X^3+X^2+1$ are:
$$
\Bbb O, (0,1),(1,\omega),(1,\omega^2),(\omega,1),(\omega,\omega^2),(\omega^2,1),(\omega^2,\omega)\,,
$$
eight in all, and the first four make up the subgroup you’re interested in. Notation: $\omega$ is an element of $\Bbb F_4$ not in $\Bbb F_2$. For instance, $[2](\omega,1)=(1,\omega^2)$, if I haven’t slipped up in my pencil-work.

Comment: Thank you for your time Lubin, $F$-plane analysis aside (which I wasn't familiar and I thank you), I am indeed aware of the "practical endgame" of your analysis, i.e. that exactly half of the points $Q\in E(F)$ are of the form $[2](P)$. Unfortunately, my problem set lies in being able to prove whether a given arbitrary point of the curve is a member of this image/set or not.  ps. I am also working on more types of curves, i.e. $Y^2+XY=X^3+b$ and $Y^2=X^3+b$, with $b∈F$ in case you can differentiate although I am aware that the last type does not apply to binary extension but to prime fields.

Comment: [continued] also, by "constructing polynomial" I mean a primitive, irreducible polynomial $f(x)$ of degree $m$ that constructs $Z_{2^m}[x]/f(x)$ which includes all elements of $GF(2^m)$ as polynomials.